# Equivalent of tf.linalg.diag_part in PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

As I'm reimplementing some code, I'm wondering if there is any equivalent of `tf.linalg.diag_part` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/diag)) in `PyTorch` ..?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a direct equivalent. However, you can get away using [`torch.diag`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diag.html):

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                      [5, 6, 7, 8]])

>>> torch.diag(x.flatten()).reshape(-1, 4, 2, 4).sum(-2)
tensor([[[1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 3, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 4]],

        [[5, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 6, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 7, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 8]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `torch.diagonal`, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/matrix-diagonal-part/47446/2 :

```
import torch 
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
r = np.array([[[0.1000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
               [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
               [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
               [0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000, 0.1000]],

              [[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
               [0.3000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000],
               [0.0400, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000],
               [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]])

tf.linalg.diag_part(r)
#returns
#<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
#array([[0.1, 0. , 0. , 0.1],
#       [0. , 0.2, 0.5, 0. ]], dtype=float32)>


torch.diagonal(torch.tensor(r), dim1=-2, dim2=-1)

#returns
#tensor([[0.1000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1000],
#        [0.0000, 0.2000, 0.5000, 0.0000]])
```